# Tornado supports absolute URI

Tags: tornado

I have one server using Tornado, it works with relative URI:
Ex: http://localhost:8085:getIpAddr
but it doesn't work with absolute uri
Ex: http://localhost:8085http://localhost:8085/getIpAddr

So, is there any setting in tornado to trigger this function? or any workaround ?

Comment: i thinks that your address have "/" between port number and path: " http://localhost:8085/getIpAddr"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this style for your all url patterns:

```
(r'/', main.IndexHandler, None, 'index'),
(r'^/getIpAddr[/]?$', main.GetIpAddrHandler),
(r'^/getIpAddr$', main.GetIpAddrHandler, None, 'getIpAddr'),
...
```